# Second projector detected but not displaying any image (blue screen "no input signal")

Tags: hdmi, resolution, external-display, asus-laptop, display-driver

I have searched a lot in the internet and couldn't make my ASUS VivoBook Pro N580VD properly display in projectors in Windows 10. The projector stays in a blue screen and displays a message saying "no input signal".
The notebook does work, properly display both in extended and duplicate modes, when in use with an external Dell Monitor connected through HDMI, but when using HDMI in projectors it doesn't.

I attach some images to help give an idea of the current state of the problem:

[When in Printing screen it shows both screens as if everything were normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2MBG.jpg)

[Both displays detected in the Display settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RucI9.png)

[Device manager window, showing I have the two displays and the display adaptors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8b7W.png)

[Intel HD Graphics control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN1xf.jpg)

In [this link](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f25/solved-2nd-monitor-detected-but-not-displaying-603390.html) in the last answer explains that using the Intel control panel to reduce the refresh rate might work (using Custom Resolutions). I could make it work in one projector once. But I have used the same projector again and it doesn't work anymore.

I have already updated the drivers using the automatic Windows 10 search for updates option. My current versions are 23.20.16.4877 for Intel(R) HD Graphics 630 and 22.21.13.8253 for NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050.

I'm basically out of ideas. Any help?

EDIT: I tested again in a room where video (projector) and audio (speakers in the ceiling) were supported just by plugging the HDMI cable.
The audio works fine, but the video doesn't. Same behavior, detected, but there's no image at all.

EDIT 2: I tested with Ubuntu Gnome (Dual boot in the same notebook), and it seems that I have the same problem in Linux.

Comment: I found this saying that playing something with sound might help. I will try that later and update here.
https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/second-monitor-is-detected-but-no-signal-pc-to-tv-via-hdmi/

Comment: You've failed to state what exactly *doesn't* work.

Comment: The projector does not receive input from my laptop. It is blue and says "no input", although it is detected by the computer. Does this clarify?

Comment: @gronostaj Do you have any clue of what could solve this? Did you understande the problem?

Comment: Yes, it's clearer now, but I don't know how to solve your problem.

Comment: Playing sound as suggested in the link I posted in the first comment didn't help...